# How to get data attached to curl function in server side??

Tags: php, post, curl, wordpress

I have to pass an array of data to server and also get response from server ..I am getting undefined variable error on clientside.php where i am trying to print_r the recieved ..How do i get the response at the server side and send it back to client side with additional information ..I am using curl function to achieve this ..

My clientside.php

```
 $url = "http://some_ip_address/../../../../serverside.php";
    //$abc is variable which contains all data in array format 
    $abc;
    $post_data = array('data' => serialize($abc)); 
    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {
        echo 0;
        } else {
        echo 1;
        }


$output= curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
curl_close ($ch);
```

My Serverside.php goes like this

```
print_r($_POST['data']);
```

I am getting the following error

```
*Notice: Undefined index: data*
```

Comment: try to `print_r($_REQUEST);` and check what is output?

Comment: Use something like firebug to view the curl request made to see if it is actually sending the values as POST or even at all.

Comment: Error gone but i m not getting data .. Only empty array is what i am getting...

Comment: If you use an array as value you have to set the correct Content-Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http_build_query():

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
```

Do not call curl_exec twice:

client.php

```
$url = "http://some_ip_address/../../../../serverside.php";
//$abc is variable which contains all data in array format 
$abc;
$post_data = array('data' => serialize($abc)); 
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$output= curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
curl_close ($ch);
```

serverside.php:

```
 print_r($_REQUEST);
```

Comment: i have used http_build_query on $abc in my case..But in order to assign a array to variable which wud be useful at server side to get the response i have that extra that extra line of $post_data = array('data' => serialize($abc));

Comment: In your case you call CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS with array, use http_build_query($post_data) or set the correct Content-Type

Comment: You get nothing because you call curl_exec twice.

Comment: i have done the above changes  but no result ...Still i m getting an emoty array ..I m using print_r($REQUEST); Any changes in server side???

Comment: underscore it print_r( $_REQUEST );

Comment: No results Tried everything ...Now at this point my server side has print_r( $_REQUEST ); and my client side consists          '$post_data = array("data=" . urlencode(serialize($abc)));          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($post_data));   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=ISO-  8859-1'));'

Comment: lets check everything (firewall or something else). Does this work?: From the client "wget http://some_ip_address/../../../../serverside.php?test=1 -O server.txt"

Comment: Yeah @andrey It works ..In array i get                           'Array
(
    [test] => 1
)'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27933/discussion-between-andrey-volk-and-user1145009)

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP doc for [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), regarding `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option:

"*If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to **multipart/form-data**.*"

You have to build a valid HTTP query string (with `http_build_query()`) or set the correct content-type, since you're using an array as a value

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
$post_data = array('data' => serialize($abc));
```

into

```
$post_data = "data=" . urlencode(serialize($abc));
```

**edit:** Also you might want to ready this answer:
[application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data/4073451#4073451)

**edit2:** And please don't forget what Andrey said about removing the first curl_exec() because you shouldn't have it twice! So remove:

```
if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {
  echo 0;
} else {
  echo 1;
}
```